# I'm trying to make a random schultz table (5x5) creator webapp

Tags: javascript

### Working

1. First we will generate a random number.
2. Then check whether it is already generated or not.
3. If not then we will push it into the array.
4. Then we will add all of the numbers into the table.

### Problem

When I am testing the code by printing all the elements of the array, any one random element always contains an undefined value.

### Code

```
var arr =[];
for(;;){
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*26);
   if(randomNum != 0 && (!arr.includes(randomNum))){
       arr.push(randomNum);
   }
   if(arr.length==25){
       break;
   }
}
arr.forEach(element => {
    console.log(arr[element]);
});
```

Comment: `element` is the value, not the key. So it will be a number between 1 and 25 while your keys are from 0 to 24 (arrays are 0-based index, the length is not)

Comment: And to fix it, you should do `console.log(element)` instead of `console.log(arr[element])`.

Comment: Or just `console.log(arr);`

Comment: Your approach is bad. Sure it "works" but if you want a random list up to 100 it'll take exponentially longer. Instead, just take an array of numbers from 1 to 25, and shuffle that array.

Answer (score 0):

`element` is the value, and you purposefully made the values 1-25. So, when you log `arr[element]` to the console, one of those is `arr[25]`. Since the length of `arr` is `25`, that's out of bounds. You should be logging `element`, not `arr[element]`.

```js
var arr =[];
for(;;){
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*26);
   if(randomNum != 0 && (!arr.includes(randomNum))){
       arr.push(randomNum);
   }
   if(arr.length==25){
       break;
   }
}
arr.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

That being said, this is not the best way to do this. It's pretty inefficient to just guess numbers over and over until you find ones you've never guessed before. A better way would be to shuffle an array of values 1-25. You can do this with plain javascript like this:

```js
var arr = [];

//fill array
for(var i = 1; i < 26; i++) arr.push(i);

//shuffle
for(var i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
  var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  var temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
}

//output
arr.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

Or, you can do this at a cryptographically secure level with [rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) like this:

```js
var arr = randoSequence(1, 25);
arr.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you want to use the randojs code, don't forget to include that `script` tag in the `head` of your html document.

Comment: Yeah it worked, thanks!! Don't mind i'm 2 months late, I was offline due to some reasons. But at the end thank tou very much, buddy.